# Mechanism of clipboard of xwindow

Tags: linux, clipboard, x11, system-calls, xorg

Can anybody explain the mechanism of clipboard of xwindow to me?
For example, if I make a operation of open a file from gedit and copy the content of this file using ctrl+c. And then I open vim and use ctrl+v to paste the content into the new opened file. I know that it will use the buffer of xwindow to store the content. But I am curious how it works in the system level. More specifically, how the underlying linux kernel needs to do to handle this copy-paste operation? Is there any system call related to this operation? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Everything you could possibly want to know about X selections but were afraid to ask](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html).