# How clipboard works in linux

Tags: linux, clipboard, copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mechanism of clipboard of xwindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271177/mechanism-of-clipboard-of-xwindow)

How does copy and paste works across different applications in linux. Does it use shared memory or is it a different process , where can see the corresponding implementation details.

Comment: This is a very reasonable question, and completely on topic for SO, if answers describe the programming API for reading and writing the selection buffer.