# C++ Get string from Clipboard on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, clipboard, x11

Hello I'm writing a c++ program and I need to get what's on clipboard into a string variable. I found a lot of solutions but all of them were written for windows. Is there any method without using the QT libraries? I found something related to X11 but not very explicit aswell.

Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271177/mechanism-of-clipboard-of-xwindow

Comment: Hmm I was looking for code that I could write and understand instead of the whole theory behind it. For example, Windows questions about clipboard are really simple to handle with simple windows functions and I heard it's a bit more complex for linux, but I can't find any example of code.
And by the way I already did this (working) in Windows side.

Comment: Then you should specify more precisely, what level of abstraction you'd like to deal with. Technically, the answer I've provided gives the information on the lowest possible level. In practice however all these boring and gory details aren't used directly, only via various wrappers/toolkits like Qt, or [Gtk+](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Clipboards.html)

Comment: BTW, here's the example of [Gtk.Clipboard](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-clipboard-examples.html.en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to find not a code first but a program with an implementation ? I did it for you and found a lot of implementations which use direct X11 calls. I think the most valuable is [this](https://code.google.com/p/rdesktop-ce/source/browse/trunk/source/xclip.cpp?spec=svn49&r=49) but also you may read [this](http://wahjava.wordpress.com/2006/08/05/x-cut-and-paste-aka-x-clipboard/). Just find any program and look for the sources. Try to look on wikipedia what applications use x11 clipboard/selection system.

> The following programs specifically operate on data transfer
>   mechanisms:
>
> `xcutsel` transfers data from selections to cut buffers or vice versa
>
> `xclipboard`, `glipper` (Gnome), `parcellite` (LXDE), and `klipper` (KDE) are
>   clipboard managers, maybe `wmcliphist` as well `xcb` shows the content of
>   the cut buffers and allows the user to manipulate them xselection,
>
> `xclip`, `xsel` and `xcopy` are command line programs that copy data to or
>   from the X selection. xcopy has a verbosity option that helps debug X
>   selection issues. parcellite also has the ability to read from and
>   write to specific X selections from the command line.
>
> `synergy` is a cross platform tool that allows you to share a clipboard across
>   multiple computers running multiple operating systems
>
> `xfce4-clipman-plugin` is a "clipboard history plugin for the Xfce4
>   panel" and also a clipboard manager xtranslate looks up words in the
>   Xselection in a multi-lingual dictionary autocutsel syncs cut buffer
>   and selection buffer

Shortly, in theory, X11 has 2 "clipboards": actually a keyboard and for selections - the text you selected immediately can be pasted anywhere you want by pressing middle-mouse button while actual "keyboard" is made for main/default clipboard purposes as exchange by different kind of objects.

P.S. I'd not work with x11 anymore after my experience. Enjoy :)

Comment: Yes I did look for implementations and I'm actually trying some with no success yet

Comment: That's why I said "I'd not work with X11 anymore" :) Qt and some libraries may have workarounds for known and unfixed x11-/xlibs bugs so you may need to try and spent some nights in order to get something work. And that's I've said "Enjoy :)".

Comment: aahah yes I see what you mean :P

Comment: I'd mark the other post as answer, since this one only has links to other code and no explanation or inner structure. The post by @x11user is really good.

Answer (score 38):

X11 uses a flexible multi-buffer multi-format asynchronous application-side clipboard protocol.

Most toolkits have it implemented (GTK's `gtk_clipboard_get()`, Qt's `QApplication::clipboard()`, Tk's [clipboard_get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16189232/8277616)). But you can do it manually with X11 API, for example, if you're not using toolkits, or if you must pass large amount of data through clipboard buffer without keeping it all in memory at the same time.

#### Theory

There may be many buffers, but you only need to know about two:

- `CLIPBOARD` is the usual explicit buffer: you copy things there with Edit/Copy menu, and paste it with Edit/Paste menu.
- `PRIMARY` selection is an implicit mouse selection feature: text gets in it when selected with mouse cursor, and gets pasted from it on middle-click in text input fields.

Primary selection needs no keypresses, so it's useful for copying small fragments between windows that are next to each other. This feature is mostly unix-specific, but I've seen putty, trillian and some gtk apps emulating it on Windows OS. Also firefox has "Paste & Go" feature when middle-clicking empty non-interactive space of the page.

To optimize things those are **application-side** buffers: instead of pushing entire clipboard/selection to the server every time it changes, application just tells the server "I own it". To get the buffer you ask the owner to give you its content. This way even a large buffer takes no resources until its actually requested.

When requesting the buffer you ask the owner for a specific format you need. For example an image copied from seamonkey browser (right-click an image and press "Copy Image") can be represented in different formats. It would appear as image URL if you paste it in terminal. It would become a picture loaded from that URL if you paste it in libreoffice writer. And it'd be the image itself if pasted in gimp. That works because seamonkey is smart and provides each application with format it asks for: text string for terminal, html for libreoffice and image data for gimp. To request text format you'd ask for `UTF8_STRING` format with fallback to `STRING`.

As you ask another application to prepare the buffer, and that may take some time, the request is **asynchronous**: the owner prepares the buffer, saves it in a specified location (window property is used as a temporary storage) and notifies you with `SelectionNotify` event when it's done.

So to get the buffer:

- choose buffer name (`CLIPBOARD`, `PRIMARY`), format
  (`UTF8_STRING`, `STRING`) and a window property to store result to
- call `XConvertSelection()` to request the buffer
- wait for `SelectionNotify` event
- read buffer content from window property

#### Naive implementation

```c
// gcc -o xclipget xclipget.c -lX11
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

Bool PrintSelection(Display *display, Window window, const char *bufname, const char *fmtname)
{
  char *result;
  unsigned long ressize, restail;
  int resbits;
  Atom bufid = XInternAtom(display, bufname, False),
       fmtid = XInternAtom(display, fmtname, False),
       propid = XInternAtom(display, "XSEL_DATA", False),
       incrid = XInternAtom(display, "INCR", False);
  XEvent event;

  XConvertSelection(display, bufid, fmtid, propid, window, CurrentTime);
  do {
    XNextEvent(display, &event);
  } while (event.type != SelectionNotify || event.xselection.selection != bufid);

  if (event.xselection.property)
  {
    XGetWindowProperty(display, window, propid, 0, LONG_MAX/4, False, AnyPropertyType,
      &fmtid, &resbits, &ressize, &restail, (unsigned char**)&result);

    if (fmtid == incrid)
      printf("Buffer is too large and INCR reading is not implemented yet.\n");
    else
      printf("%.*s", (int)ressize, result);

    XFree(result);
    return True;
  }
  else // request failed, e.g. owner can't convert to the target format
    return False;
}

int main()
{
  Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  unsigned long color = BlackPixel(display, DefaultScreen(display));
  Window window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0,0, 1,1, 0, color, color);
  Bool result = PrintSelection(display, window, "CLIPBOARD", "UTF8_STRING") ||
                PrintSelection(display, window, "CLIPBOARD", "STRING");
  XDestroyWindow(display, window);
  XCloseDisplay(display);
  return !result;
}
```

This will work for many simple cases. One thing missing here is support for incremental reading of large buffers. Let's add it!

#### Large buffers

Some apps may want to copy/paste 100 gigabytes of text logs. And X11 allows that! But the data must be passed incrementally, split into chunks.

If the requested buffer is too large, instead of storing it into the window property, owner sets a property of format `INCR`. If you delete it, owner assumes you've read it, and puts next chunk in the same property. That continues until the last chunk is read and deleted. Finally owner sets property of size 0 to mark the end of data.

So to read large buffer you delete `INCR` property and wait for the property to appear again (`PropertyNotify` event, state == `PropertyNewValue`), read and delete it, wait for it to appear again, and so on until it appears with zero size.

```c
// gcc -o xclipget xclipget.c -lX11
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

Bool PrintSelection(Display *display, Window window, const char *bufname, const char *fmtname)
{
  char *result;
  unsigned long ressize, restail;
  int resbits;
  Atom bufid = XInternAtom(display, bufname, False),
       fmtid = XInternAtom(display, fmtname, False),
       propid = XInternAtom(display, "XSEL_DATA", False),
       incrid = XInternAtom(display, "INCR", False);
  XEvent event;

  XSelectInput (display, window, PropertyChangeMask);
  XConvertSelection(display, bufid, fmtid, propid, window, CurrentTime);
  do {
    XNextEvent(display, &event);
  } while (event.type != SelectionNotify || event.xselection.selection != bufid);

  if (event.xselection.property)
  {
    XGetWindowProperty(display, window, propid, 0, LONG_MAX/4, True, AnyPropertyType,
      &fmtid, &resbits, &ressize, &restail, (unsigned char**)&result);
    if (fmtid != incrid)
      printf("%.*s", (int)ressize, result);
    XFree(result);

    if (fmtid == incrid)
      do {
        do {
          XNextEvent(display, &event);
        } while (event.type != PropertyNotify || event.xproperty.atom != propid || event.xproperty.state != PropertyNewValue);

        XGetWindowProperty(display, window, propid, 0, LONG_MAX/4, True, AnyPropertyType,
          &fmtid, &resbits, &ressize, &restail, (unsigned char**)&result);
        printf("%.*s", (int)ressize, result);
        XFree(result);
      } while (ressize > 0);

    return True;
  }
  else // request failed, e.g. owner can't convert to the target format
    return False;
}

int main()
{
  Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  unsigned long color = BlackPixel(display, DefaultScreen(display));
  Window window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0,0, 1,1, 0, color, color);
  Bool result = PrintSelection(display, window, "CLIPBOARD", "UTF8_STRING") ||
                PrintSelection(display, window, "CLIPBOARD", "STRING");
  XDestroyWindow(display, window);
  XCloseDisplay(display);
  return !result;
}
```

For example `xsel` tool uses `INCR` transfer for buffers larger than 4000. According to ICCCM, it's up to the application to choose a reasonable size limit.

The same code works for `PRIMARY` selection. Replace "CLIPBOARD" with "PRIMARY" to print `PRIMARY` selection contents.

#### References

- [X Selections summary](https://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html) by Jamie Zawinski
- [Xlib Programming Manual](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/selection.html) - Selections
- [ICCCM](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2.7.2) - Large Data Transfers and INCR protocol
- https://github.com/exebook/x11clipboard - minimal `XCopy()` and `XPaste()` implementations
- `xsel` and `xclip` sources
- [The Secondary Selection](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~chl/secondary-selection.html) - history and ideas by Charles Lindsey

Comment: This answer was beautiful. X11 gurus are so rare. Who are you?

Comment: Never thanked you for your effort here! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this was the end of a long search for this information, thanks.